# Combining login based auth with saml 2 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

My goal is to add SSO way in addition to login based into spring boot app.
I use Okta as identity provider and got stuck into misunderstanding conceptions:
When I follow single sign on url from Okta, it goes to localhost endpoint and falls with 415 response. My websecurity config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(SECURITY_WHITELIST)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                /* configuring saml*/
                .and()
                .saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
                // .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class).antMatcher("/**/auth-saml")  //
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
 
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

and controller's endpoint signature with console exception log:

```
  @PostMapping(value = BASE_NAME,consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE )
    ResponseEntity<AuthenticationDTO> login ( @RequestBody MultiValueMap body);
```

`https://pastebin.com/UREcv7CW`

Do I get it correctly that 415 response occurs due to token based configuration and it cant retrieve it from the header? Also any advice to configure both ways of authentication are welcome. Thanks!

ps: spring security config -

```
spring:                                                                       
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          okta:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: https://www.okta.com/************
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: classpath:credentials/okta.cert
              singlesignon.url: https://trial-8410773.okta.com/app/trial-********/sso/saml
              singlesignon.sign-request: false
```

Comment: Now Im focused on setting single sso . So , after very basic yaml configuration it falls with  followed exception: ```https://pastebin.com/a8D3z5UB``` . According to the log it can't apply creds given from Okta and falls back into default ROLE_ANONIMOUS and got 403. As user I see half-minute period of attemptions to relogin and 429 code after all.

Comment: Invalid assertion [id375715554935288561550335403] for SAML response [id37571555493389223699622518]: Condition '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}AudienceRestriction' of type 'null' in assertion 'id375715554935288561550335403' was not valid.: None of the audiences within Assertion 'id375715554935288561550335403' matched the list of valid audiances